# How do I insert into a table the value of one field in a datagridview that changes?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am allowing the user to make changes to one row of one column in the datagrid view whos datasource is bound to a table (ProductTable). When the datagridview loads, it reflects the columns and rows of the table. There is only ever going to be just one row in the datagridview. I set the readonly property of one column to false which will be the "Totals" column. When the user changes the cell value of the "Totals" column, I want there there to be an SQL insert query that happens on cell value change event which inserts into the table the value that was put into the datagridview by the user and inserts it into the same column/row of the table ("Totals").

```
Private Sub datagridview1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles datagridview1.CellValueChanged

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into ProductsTable (Totals) VALUES (@Totals)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Totals", SqlDbType.Int).Value = datagridview1.Rows(1).Cells(1).ColumnIndex("Totals")

           If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
           cmd.ExecuteScalar()
           con.Close()

End Sub
```

My cmd.parameters.add value needs corrected. I just need to grab the one value that gets changed under the totals column and put the new value into the table.

Comment: Rather than update one column at a time, a DataTable will store up all the changes and a DataAdapter will apply them all for you.

Comment: There is no way that code of yours could be compiled. `datagridview1.Rows(1).Cells(1).ColumnIndex("Totals")` is wrong. Change it to `datagridview1.Rows(1).Cells("Totals").Value`